# SES.sendRawEmail Only Uses The First Attachment In Gmail (Nodejs)

Tags: email, html-email, mime-types, email-attachments, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email with multiple attachments using AWS SES and nodejs.

My js script calls ses.sendRawEmail like so:

```
const params = {
    RawMessage: {
      Data: rawMailBody
    },
    Destinations: [],
    Source: 'testemail@gmail.com'
  };

  ses.sendRawEmail(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log("Error: " + err);
    else {

      // console.log("Success call: ", JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log("Success.");

      return data
    }

  });
```

This is how I am creating the "rawMailBody" object:

```
const BUCKET = 'my-bucket';
var rawMailBody = "From: testemail@gmail.com\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "To: testemail@gmail.com\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "Subject: Test Subject\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + ``
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "--NextPart\n";

  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "\n";

  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + htmlData;

  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "--NextPart\n";

  console.log('attaching attachments')

  const attachmentFilename = 'Evaluates2-Old-Logo.pdf';
  const attachmentFilename2 = '2019-W-4.pdf';

  console.log('adding attachment', attachmentFilename)
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "Content-ID: random1565323918273545letters\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + 'Content-Disposition: attachment; name="Evaluates2-Old-Logo.pdf"; filename="Evaluates2-Old-Logo.pdf";\n';
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + await getImgDataBuffer('Evaluates2-Old-Logo.pdf', BUCKET); + "\n\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "--NextPart\n";

  console.log('adding attachment', attachmentFilename2)
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "Content-ID: random1565323443423794letters\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + 'Content-Disposition: attachment; name="2019-W-4.pdf"; filename="2019-W-4.pdf";\n';
  // rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "Content-ID random3965323447923784letters\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + await getImgDataBuffer('2019-W-4.pdf', BUCKET); + "\n\n";
  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "--NextPart\n";

  rawMailBody = rawMailBody + "--NextPart--\n";
```

I am getting the image data base64 buffer like this:

```
const getImgDataBuffer = (imageFilename, bucket) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: imageFilename };

    s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {

      if (err) {

        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred

        reject(err)
      }
      else {
        console.log(data.ContentLength);
        console.log(data.ContentType);
        console.log(data.Body);

        console.log('got ', imageFilename)
        resolve(data.Body.toString('base64'))
      }
    })

  })

}
```

I am getting very strange behavior in gmail- it only takes the first pdf I send. The first pdf comes through perfectly, but the second doesn't come through at all. When I swap the order that the attachments are added to the rawMailBody object it still renders only the first one.

When I choose "show original" in gmail I can see that the entire MIME block for the second attachment is completely missing...

Is this expected behavior for gmail to remove subsequent attachments after the first one? Am I just doing it wrong?

Thanks!